# React: how to fetch multiple API's

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Live code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fetch-api-ce987).

Using the NHL APi, trying to make a React app that simply displays the each player's information. The code does work right now (returns general roster information, and one specific player's data), but I want to display all of the team's players info. Not just one.

I'm new to working with multiple API's and there's about 47 players. Do I really have to fetch each player individually, making 47 API calls?

Or is there a better way? Wondering if I'm able to fetch the roster API once, and then somehow show all of the individual player's information from there.

Any help would be very appreciated!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    roster: null,
    spezza: null
  };

  // Always fetch here

  async componentDidMount() {
    // Roster
    const api = "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/10/roster";
    const response = await fetch(api);
    const data = await response.json();

    console.log(data.roster[0]);

    // Spezza
    const apiSpezza = "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8469455";
    const responseSpezza = await fetch(apiSpezza);
    const dataSpezza = await responseSpezza.json();

    console.log(dataSpezza.people[0]);

    // When the component mounts, set the new state values based on the API
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      roster: data.roster[0],
      spezza: dataSpezza.people[0]
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {/* If loading = true - meaning we can't fetch the API, then display loading.
        If loading value = false, meaning we fetched it, display the values from the API */}
        {this.state.loading ? (
          <div>loading...</div>
        ) : (
          <>
            <h1>Roster:</h1>
            <p>Jersey Number: {this.state.roster.jerseyNumber}</p>
            <p>Full Name: {this.state.roster.person.fullName}</p>
            <h1>Spezza:</h1>
            <p>Jersey Number: {this.state.spezza.primaryNumber}</p>
            <p>Age: {this.state.spezza.currentAge}</p>
            <p>Height: {this.state.spezza.height}</p>
            <p>Weight: {this.state.spezza.weight} lbs</p>
            <p>Nationalty: {this.state.spezza.nationality}</p>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Can you link to the NHA API documentation?

Comment: You could try [`axios.all`](https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Axios.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index) and then make multiple `axios.gets`

Comment: @Bodrov, It doesn't look like he's using axios.

Answer (score 0):

So in looking at the [documentation that I could find on the NHL API](https://gitlab.com/dword4/nhlapi/blob/master/stats-api.md), it doesn't appear that they have a way to call multiple users stats in one request like they do for teams.

My suggest would be to do a Promise.all() against the requests or at the very least move your await to where the data is being used so all of the requests can fire off at once and then wait for all of them to come back. As it stands, you're firing off the first request, waiting for it to come back, then firing off the next request.

Answer (score 0):

If the API does not have a route which accepts, say an array of player ID's and returns all of the populated details, then yes, you will need to make all of the calls individually.  There are ways to accomplish this, using axios as one of the commenters suggested or [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) with the native Fetch API, but repeating so many network requests will probably add a noticeable load time to your page.

Answer (score 0):

```
Promise.all([
    fetch(apiSpezza),
    fetch(api),
  ]).then(([data1, data2]) => {
cosnole.log(data1,data2);
})
```

I will recommend call API using localhost and don't pass API URL directly .

Answer (score 0):

Even better than Promise.all would be Promise.allSettled. The difference from Promise.all is that it will not fail just because a single call fails. It's a new api so if you care at all about widespread support you will need to polyfill it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Something along the lines of:

```
const results = await Promise.allSettled(fetch(data.roster.map(player => 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/${player.id}')));
const people = await results.filter(p => p.status === 'fulfilled').map(p => p.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the long answer but I believe this is the correct way to do this

I would divide the list and list items in 2 separate components like this.

Keep the component you have like it is just cut out the section where you make the call for Spezza

```
...
// Spezza
const apiSpezza = "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8469455";
const responseSpezza = await fetch(apiSpezza);
const dataSpezza = await responseSpezza.json();
...
```

And where you render Spezza

```
<>
    ...
    <h1>Roster:</h1>
    <p>Jersey Number: {this.state.roster.jerseyNumber}</p>
    <p>Full Name: {this.state.roster.person.fullName}</p>
    <h1>Spezza:</h1>
    <p>Jersey Number: {this.state.spezza.primaryNumber}</p>
    <p>Age: {this.state.spezza.currentAge}</p>
    <p>Height: {this.state.spezza.height}</p>
    <p>Weight: {this.state.spezza.weight} lbs</p>
    <p>Nationalty: {this.state.spezza.nationality}</p>
    ....
</>
```

Then create a new component like this:

```
class PlayerComponent extends Component {


    state = {player: {}}

    // Spezza
    const player = `https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8469455${this.props.player.person.id}`;
    const playerResponse = await fetch(player);
    const playerData= await playerResponse.json();

    this.setState({layer : playerData})


    render() {
        return (
            <>
      <h1>Roster:</h1>
                <p>Full Name: {this.state.player.fullName}</p>
                <h1>{this.state.player}</h1>
                <p>Jersey Number: {this.state.player.primaryNumber}</p>
                <p>Age: {this.state.player.currentAge}</p>
                <p>Height: {this.state.player.height}</p>
                <p>Weight: {this.state.player.weight} lbs</p>
                <p>Nationalty: {this.state.player.nationality}</p>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

And use the PlayerComponent in your Main component like this:

```
<>
    ...
    {this.state.roster.length && this.state.roster.map(player => <PlayerComponent player={player}/>)}
    ...
</>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd argue that each Player component shouldn't do its own fetch because now you have more components that have complex logic for fetching instead of just rendering dumb components. Basically the container/component (or smart/dumb component) breakdown.

Comment: I can hear the argument for that but I think it would be much easier to manage in the tong run as I assume there may be actions etc. attached to each Player and managing the scope would be way easier if each payer has it's own component.

Comment: I definitely agree each player should have their own component. My argument is just that the parent should own the data.

Comment: Oh I get it now, but In the that there would be an API to get them all in one call I might have agreed with you but as there is no API for that my opinion is the above. But I can allso hear the other side

Comment: See my answer below where you can use Promise.allSettled to perform that. Granted it's not a single api call but it's still a way to manage them all from a single spot.